Вводное слово между однородными определениями
Я засмотрелась: воздушная, казалось мягкая материя медленно и нежно шагает по водной глади.
Можно ли не ставить запятую после вводного слова «казалось»?
С одной стороны, здесь нет обособленного оборота, к которому могло бы примкнуть вводное.
А с другой – почему нет? Без второй запятой сразу понятна его отнесённость ко второму однородному определению «мягкая», да и пауза в этом сочетании ни к чему...
Я так понимаю, что сюда применимо это правило: «Вводные слова и сочетания, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой» (Грамота.ру). Но вот из примеров там только пресловутое сложное предложение: «Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня».

Александр, голос от меня за вопрос. Мое мнение вы знаете, поэтому давайте послушаем других участников. И по поводу "пресловутого предложения": там просто пропустили запятую, мне так кажется). "Ветер стучал в окна, в крышу; слышался свист, и в печи домовой жалобно и угрюмо напевал свою песенку. Был первый час ночи. В доме все уже легли, но никто не спал, и Наде всё чуялось, что внизу играют на скрипке. Послышался резкий стук, должно быть, сорвалась ставня..."  А. П. Чехов. Невеста. https://ilibrary.ru/text/1184/p.4/index.html

@Sharon Пропустить запятую они не могли, тогда само правило теряет смысл. Вот ваш вопрос с этим же правилом и лопатинским решением не ставить запятую в сложных предложениях.

Начнем с того, что у Чехова запятая стоит.  Почему они убрали запятую в правилах? Или  у них был другой текст? Я видела свой ответ и считаю, что знак нужен обязательно и по многим причинам. Грамота слушается Лопатина, а у него далеко не всё безупречно, к тому же многое противоречат практике.

@Sharon Что там было у Чехова... наверно, рукопись надо видеть или первое издание. А они взяли и подогнали предложение под своё правило, не нашли или не искали других, оригинальных примеров, где нет запятой.

У Паустовского есть:  Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой. Это  предложение для них образец, просто молятся на него. Такое письмо не соответствует грамматике ни разу, но зато их мышлению соответствует.

В качестве варианта:
Я засмотрелась: воздУшная, казалось бы мягкая матЕрия / медленно и нежно шагает по водной глади.
Пояснение

Подбор по слуху: казалось бы идеально подходит, а казалось вообще не подходит (в любом варианте). Ну и в правилах мне не встречался разбор примеров с однородными определениями.

Почему? Казалось больше похоже на предикатив по сравнению с казалось бы и затемняет структуру данного предложения.

Чем отличаются эти два вводных слова. В справочнике нет указаний (значение одинаковое), но так и это. Есть такое мнение: Казалось бы отличается от казалось тем, что предполагает, что ДОЛЖНО БЫЛО БЫ казаться. Это — предположение, не вполне уверенное. В любом случае форма сослагательного наклонения оказывает определенное влияние.

Почему нет обособления? А это переход в частицу-союз или наречие со значением  будто бы или вроде бы как, или скорее. То есть это уже не вводное слово, а другая функция.

Пример из Грамоты: Не вижу смысла сдаваться в, казалось бы, проигранной позиции... Ну вот куда здесь обособление, да еще после предлога!


ВЫВОД
Везде нужен конкретный анализ, а не следование формализму правил. Ну и грамматику нужно учитывать, в том числе особую функцию вводных слов.
А если нет обособления, то это уже не вводное слово, так как меняется синтаксическая функция. В грамматике четко указано: вводные слова могут дифференцировать однородные отношения, но при этом они остаются водными словами и обособляются.
А вот как и почему меняется функция слова – это и есть решение задачи.

Спасибо за мнение.

Так и не понимаю, почему «казалось вообще не подходит (в любом варианте)». А мне почему-то с бы не кажется идеальным, а наоборот, царапает слух. Вот такие нюансы индивидуального восприятия... :)

Мы слышим по-разному.  Наши классики в правописании позволяют нам обособлять вводное слово или нет, но эти слова индивидуальны. Если нет обособления, то слово переходит в другую часть речи, и вот этот переход нужно услышать. Возможно, вам мешает частица БЫ.  Я же слышу такой переход: воздУшная, как будто бы мягкая матЕрия.  //  А слово казалось выглядит откровенным предикативом, хотя и не является им: казалось мягкая материя. И это на слух воспринимается как несочетаемость подлежащего и сказуемого, вот что мне царапает слух.

Да, "казалось мягкая" мне тоже царапает. И тоже хотел сказать, что лучше заменить на "как будто". Без "бы" пойдёт же?

Мне больше нравится "будто бы", но "как будто" тоже нормально.

Да, "будто бы" лучше всего.

Sпасибо  за приемку ответа, понеже вельми.

Sharon, а вот здесь без запятой нормально же, правильно? Всё было отлично, я бы сказала прекрасно и волшебно. И предложение не по этой теме: Он прошёл вперёд, потом обернулся посмотрел на меня и улыбнулся. Немного корявенько, но "обернулся посмотрел" можно же расценивать не как однородные, а как одно действие, типа "стояли ждали" и пр.

Что-то я в раздумье)   В первом предложении паузы практически нет, и запятую вроде бы не хочется ставить. С другой стороны, как объяснить ее отсутствие? Лучше поставить: Всё было отлично, я бы сказала, прекрасно и волшебно.  Будем считать, что обособлено вводное предложение, а паузу в случае однородных  отношений между сказуемыми обозначить сложно.

Второе предложение.  У Кустовой о простом глагольном сказуемом:  4) другой глагол в ЛИЧНОЙ форме, обычно со значением движения или положения: сижу читаю; пойду посмотрю; пойдем посмотрим.  А у нас форма прошедшего времени. Может, с деепричастием попробовать: Он прошёл вперёд, потом обернувшись посмотрел на меня и улыбнулся.  Или что-то в этом роде, но как-то надо изменить последовательность глаголов.   Стр. 68  https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Спасибо, Шерон! В первом предложении отсутствие запятой как раз объясняется правилом. // Меня щас угнетают :) "обязательные" запятые на стыках союзов и союзов с деепричастиями. Вы много об этом писали уже, поэтому хочу задать пару вопросов в комментариях, но не здесь. Благодарю за ваше ТЕРПЕНИЕ и ТРуд  –  всё, я устал...

Ах, Александр, всем правит Грамматика))  "Обязательные" запятые предлагают правила,  которые по сути ее вассалы,  я и сама перед ними не преклоняюсь. А  эта госпожа на правила редко когда и взглянет, но ей самой и ее законам лучше не противоречить) А вот под ее защитой чувствуешь себя уверенно.  Сделайте правильный выбор) Удачи вам в вашей работе.
